# When is onAttachFragment called with a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a master ActionBarActivity, that contains a ViewPager and a associated ViewPager Adapter. When the code

```
@Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return pageToFragment(position);
        }
```

is called by swiping the view pager, is the function

```
 @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {

        super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
        }
```

called?

Is this function called every time we swipe, or just the first time?

Answer (score 1):

This will not help you any more, but I hope someone else will find this useful. Both functions should be called only once:

`getItem()` is called, when the fragment has been instantiated *the first time* with `instantiateItem()`. `instantiateItem()` can be called more than once, namely every time, you select a tab with a fragment, that has been destroyed (for example due to the `setOffscreenPageLimit()`-limit), but `getItem()` will *not* be called a second time.

`onAttachFragment()` is "called when a Fragment is being attached to this activity, immediately after the call to its Fragment.onAttach() method and before Fragment.onCreate()" (taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onAttachFragment%28android.app.Fragment%29))